# Symmetric random walk on the integers

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I found an exercise in a paper by Anupam Gupta, Sahil Singla that i couldn't solve, sadly my knowledge in Markov processes is pretty limited. The exercise is the following:

Suppose we have a symmetric random walk of length n on $\mathbb{Z}$ starting at point 0 conditioned on ending at the origin. Define $I_t$ as the position on $\mathbb{Z}$ after $t$ steps. Use a Chernoff-Hoeffding bound to show that $\max_t I_t-\min_t I_t$ is at most $O(\log n)$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{\text{poly}(n)}$.

I really do not know how to approach this, i would appreciate some help.

Comment: By "RW with length n" you mean the length of each step can take every integer in between $-n$ and $n$?

Comment: No, each step has length 1. I mean that my random walk consists of n steps in total.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but how is $\min_t I_t$ not always $0$? You're starting and ending at the origin, right?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer: I think we can start from any point, and then $\min_t I_t$ becomes some kind of a shift.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, thank you!

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer It's symmetric, which means that it can become negative.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer just pointed out an error in an early version of this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint $1$: Hoeffding's bound is usually used on sums of independent random variables (usually Bernoulli or Rademacher). What could be the sums here? What are the independent random variables?

Hint $2$: Introduce some variable for the starting position and then try to figure out how $I_t$ can be expressed such that this starting position does not appear in the formula.

Hint $3$: Bound the probability that $|I_t|$ is large using Hoeffding.

Hint $4$: Recall the Union Bound.

Solution:
Let $X_i$ be the random variable which denotes the direction of the $i$-th step i.e. it is $-1$ with probability $1/2$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $s$ denote our starting point. As given in the exercise, we condition on the fact that $s + \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i = 0$. Hence $I_t$ is given by $I_t = s + \sum_{i = 1}^t X_i = \sum_{i = t + 1}^n X_i$ and has mean $0$. In particular, by the [Hoeffding bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) we have that
$$\text{P}(|I_t| \geq c \log n) \leq 2 \exp \left ( - \frac{(n - t)^2c^2\log^2n}{4(n - t)}\right) \leq 2 \exp \left ( - \frac{c^2\log^2n}{4}\right).$$
Using the Union-Bound we hence get
$$\text{P}(\max_t I_t - \min_t I_t \geq 2c \log n) \leq 2n \exp \left ( - \frac{c^2\log^2n}{4}\right) = \frac{2n}{n^{\frac{c^2\log n}{4}}}.$$

We conclude that we get $\max_t I_t - \min_t I_t = \mathcal{O}(\log n)$ with probability at least $1 - \frac{1}{\text{poly}(n)}$.